# Critical error and failing to parse data returned by server

Tags: oracle-12c, oracle-sql-developer

I am currently running `Oracle 12c`, but unfortunately I am getting this critical error message:

> Fail to parse data returned by server

I have never seen this error before and every attempt at finding a solution as been unsuccessful. I am rather a newbie in the world of Oracle DB.

Your help will be very much appreciated.

So far I am able to connect to the database with SQL Developer, but when `Enterprise Manager` is giving me the critical error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failure to parse data returned by server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143162/failure-to-parse-data-returned-by-server)

Comment: Well if it is a duplicate, then there is no answer to the previous question. The person provided a link to an oracle website that requires one to have oracle support subscription account

Comment: This question has not been answered if click on the link above you will see that supposedly duplicate question still doesn't have an answer, I will like to know why are you claiming that the problem has been solved it is clearly not.